# Unable to select the any particular from dropdown tried all option _Able to click but after then not working

Tags: python, selenium

drop_down1 = driver.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value="/html/body/main/div[2]/form/div[4]/div[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NBokt.png)/div/div[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NBokt.png)")
drop_down1.click()
time.sleep(3)
drop_down2 = driver.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value="/html/body/main/div[2]/form/div[4]/div[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NBokt.png)/select/option[2]")
drop_down2.click()

## Another option

grade_dropdown = Select(driver.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value="/html/body/main/div[2]/form/div[4]/div[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NBokt.png)/select"))

## Another option

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NBokt.png)grade_dropdown = Select(driver.find_element(by=By.ID, value="Choose a delivery method"))
grade_dropdown.select_by_visible_text("Pdf by email")

Comment: Please give a link to the site or paste the HTML body

Comment: Please update formatting of the code to be more readable and includes all necessary information needed to answer this question.